# Write/WriteLine strange behaviour

Tags: c#, file, stream

I have a ini-like file structure I want to read from:

```
[section1]
param1=value1
param2=value2
etc...
```

And here the code:

```
string inputLine;
// Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
// the file is reached.
while ((inputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
    {
        string[] values = inputLine.Split(new Char[] { '=' });
        Console.WriteLine(values[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I remove all the `[section]` parts, I can read all parameters just fine. But if I decide to keep them, the  `Console.Write(inputLine)Console.Write` fails. I also tried `Console.Write(inputLine[0])` and it also gives me an error, which leads me to think the `[` character is the problem somehow...

The Write/WriteLine is just a test mechanism, what I really want in the end is to `char.IsLetter(inputStream[0])` to check if the first character of the line is a letter and if so, skip it, since I'm just interested in reading the key-value pairs of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to read the second item in the array `values` when the link `[section]` splitted by `=` results in a single-item array. You could skip all lines that begin with `[` to fix this:

```
string inputLine;
// Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
// the file is reached.
while ((inputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputLine) || inputLine.StartsWith("[")) {
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
    {
        string[] values = inputLine.Split(new Char[] { '=' });
        Console.WriteLine(values[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works like I wanted, what if I want to "continue" either if row starts with "[" or if it's empty?

Comment: @Bersekz I've edited the post to include a null-or-empty check.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an empty line between sections?
Because that is where you would get an error on inputLine[0].

Answer (score 0):

You should be validating that the line you read has data before trying to access any of the values you tried to parse from it, otherwise you can get an error like the other 2 answers indicate (because there is only 1 value parsed or 0 characters read from the line).

```
string testInput =
   "[section1]\r\n" +
   "param1=value1\r\n" +
   "param2=value2\r\n\r\n" +
   "[section2]\r\n" +
   "parama=valuea";

using (var reader = new System.IO.StringReader(testInput))
{
   string inputLine;
   while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      string[] values = inputLine.Split(new char[] {'='}, 2);
      if (values.Length > 1)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Value of {0} is {1}", values[0], values[1]);
      }
      else
         Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" has {1} characters and {2} values on it", inputLine, inputLine.Length, values.Length);       }
}
```

The output is:

```
"[section1]" has 10 characters and 1 values on it
Value of param1 is value1
Value of param2 is value2
"" has 0 characters and 1 values on it
"[section2]" has 10 characters and 1 values on it
Value of parama is valuea
```